# Execute Multiple Methods Simaltaneously Using Thread In Java

Tags: java, multithreading

In my case I have three methods of three different class. First one is Run the Services continuously by running jar file, Second one is check if any services is down, if not down let it be and if any of the services is down run the service by running jar file and third one is insert the log in database as well as in text file.

I have done this but its not functioning properly.

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
      Runjar.Runservices();
   }
};
Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
      ControllerApplication.linuxCmd();
   }
};
Thread thread3 = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
      Utils.insertLog();
   }
};
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread3.start();
```

How can i handle it in java in simple and effective way.  Sample code examples more preferred. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  What code have you worked with?  What reading have you done?

Comment: I have done this but it is not functioning properly.

Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Runjar.Runservices();
            }
        };
    
            Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                ControllerApplication.linuxCmd();
            }
        };
            
            Thread thread3 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Utils.insertLog();
            }
        };
            
            
            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();
            thread3.start();

Comment: How is it not functioning properly? What behavior do you expect that this code does not get you?

Comment: Is your problem that each of the methods executes only once and you want them to continue executing again and again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call all these methods continuously in a loop then just change your code to following :

```
volatile boolean runServices = true;
volatile boolean linuxCmd = true;
volatile boolean insertLog = true;
int SLEEP_TIME = 100;//Configurable. 
Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
       while (runServices)
       {
           try
           {
                Runjar.Runservices();
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);//So that other thread also get the chance to execute.
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }

       }    
   }
};
Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
       while (linuxCmd)
       {
           try
           {
                ControllerApplication.linuxCmd();
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);//So that other thread also get the chance to execute.
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
};
Thread thread3 = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
       while (insertLog)
       {
           try
           {
                Utils.insertLog();
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);//So that other thread also get the chance to execute.
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

   }
};
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread3.start();
```

> If you want to stop runServices then change `runServices` to `false`.
>   Similarly for `linuxCmd` and `insertLog`