# Java execute 3 methods at same time inside custom method and grab values from run methods

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-7, thread-synchronization

I would like to execute 3 methods at same time in Java (obviously I need threads), and that **I would like to execute not in separate class and not in my main method, but in my custom method. Can it be done?**

I have find this piece of code - [Execute Multiple Methods Simaltaneously Using Thread In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534216/execute-multiple-methods-simaltaneously-using-thread-in-java) 
and reused best marked answer for my example, with parameters that I have:

```
private void fetchData() {

    boolean t1_run = true;
    boolean t2_run = true;
    boolean t3_run = true;
    int SLEEP_TIME = 100;//Configurable. 
    Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
       public void run() {
           while (t1_run)
           {
               try
               {
                    subjects = new BeanItemContainer<KltSubject>(KltSubject.class, clijentService.getSubjecteByType(Integer.valueOf(creditor)));
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);//So that other thread also get the chance to execute.
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }

           }    
       }
    };
    Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
       public void run() {
           while (t2_run)
           {
               try
               {
                    programs = new BeanItemContainer<Program>(Program.class, creditService.getAllPrograms());
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);//So that other thread also get the chance to execute.
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }
    };
    Thread thread3 = new Thread() {
       public void run() {
           while (t3_run)
           {
               try
               {
                    credits = new BeanItemContainer<CreditExt>(CreditExt.class, creditService.getAllCredits());
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);//So that other thread also get the chance to execute.
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }
           }

       }
    };
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();
}
```

Now, before I've put my variables in threads (**variables named: subjects, programs and credits**), I could easily get their values (**these variables you can see in above code in this example in their run methods, but are defined outside my fetchData() method and are visible**).

**After setting code like this, and executing it, I recieve null pointer exception because obviously varaibles are not seen any more after threads are executed. How to get that values after execution in threads?**

**P.S.** can this code be written more elegantly, with less lines of code? If Java 8 (or Java 7) can done it - show me please how?

Answer (score 1):

Use advanced Threading API : [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) `invokeAll()`

```
<T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
                       throws InterruptedException
```

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. `Future.isDone()` is true for each element of the returned list. Note that a completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception. The results of this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while this operation is in progress.

Sample code:

```
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    List<MyCallable> futureList = new ArrayList<MyCallable>();

    MyCallable1 myCallable1 = new MyCallable1(); // your first thread
    MyCallable2 myCallable2 = new MyCallable2(); // your second thread
    MyCallable3 myCallable1 = new MyCallable3(); // your third thread
    futureList.add(myCallable1);
    futureList.add(myCallable2);
    futureList.add(myCallable3);

    System.out.println("Start");
    try{
        List<Future<Long>> futures = service.invokeAll(futureList);  
        for(Future<Long> future : futures){
            try{
                System.out.println("future.isDone = " + future.isDone());
                System.out.println("future: call ="+future.get());
            }
            catch(Exception err1){
                err1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception err){
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
    service.shutdown();
```

You can have a look into few more examples in this [article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)

Comment: Only here is a problem - it assumens that I will add in futureList class objects (i mean another class instances). And my objects are not from other classes, they are from same class. This invokeAll() method would be useless to me, because I would already had to execute it to even pass it (or how would I pass that method name to execute later in within same class if I don't want to create another class for it?). How to solve it with that sort of case?

Comment: From the code your have posted, I don't see any sharing of data between these threads.  You can declare three Threads in same class as inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join()` to wait for the threads to finish. 
eg:

```
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
thread3.join();
```

when all the threads are done, the variables shouldn't be null.
Making this more compact depends on what exactly you're trying to do. Here is an example:

```
private List<Result> fetchData() {
    final List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Result result = getResult();
                synchronized(results) {
                    results.add(result);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        threads.add(t);
    }
    for(Thread t:threads) {
        t.join();
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: My code runs forever now after I've done this. Should I edit sleep time.. and how?

Comment: @DarioBB It runs forever because of the `while` loops, you need to make those `boolean` values `volatile` and change them to `false` at some point.

Comment: But when? How can I discover when thread is executed? P.s. can I do it without while loops?

Comment: @DarioBB if you call `join()` on a thread, the execution will block until that thread finishes.

Comment: I don't see any speed gain when I solve it like this. If it was database pulls those variables got.. that would not even needed to get some speen gain?

Comment: @DarioBB I've edited my answer to make it so that the work will be done  outside of the `synchronized`. Also, you need to make sure that all threads were started before calling `join()` on any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `CompletableFuture`:

```
CompletableFuture<BeanItemContainer<KltSubject>> job1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
    new BeanItemContainer<>(KltSubject.class, clijentService.getSubjecteByType(creditor)));
CompletableFuture<BeanItemContainer<Program>> job2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
    new BeanItemContainer<>(Program.class, creditService.getAllPrograms()));
CompletableFuture<BeanItemContainer<CreditExt>> job3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
    new BeanItemContainer<>(CreditExt.class, creditService.getAllCredits()));
subjects = job1.join();
programs = job2.join();
credits  = job3.join();
```

The method `supplyAsync` will initiate the asynchronous computation of a value and `join` will return the computed value, waiting, if necessary. But if all three actions imply querying the same database, it might be possible, that you don’t gain any performance advantage as the database may be the limiting factor.

Comment: Thank you, and this is it.. no need for any threads? Is this approach better than with ExecutorService?

Comment: This creates (and re-uses) threads behind the scenes to process the asynchronous jobs. The `ExecutorService` gives you more control over the thread policies wheres the `CompletableFuture` usage is simpler. But note that even code using the `ExecutorService` doesn’t need to be that complicated. You can almost do the same by calling `submit` on the `ExecutorService` three times, followed by invoking `get()` on each returned `Future` instance.